# Blank output when trying to box bolded number

Tags: python, pdf, ocr

I'm currently working on a program that lets users pick a multiple choice question and its mark scheme in PDF format(as shown below). The program scans both of the PDF file and identifies bolded numbers as the question numbers. I've added a margin to exclude the top and bottom of the page since they might contain bolded page numbers. Once the numbers are identified, the program boxes the individual questions by selecting the area between the two bolded numbers. (Currently the code only includes the processing for the question file as I'm figuring out how the OCR works)

The question paper: https://www.cambridgeinternational.org/Images/520512-june-2021-question-paper-21.pdf

The answer paper:https://www.cambridgeinternational.org/Images/520494-june-2021-mark-scheme-paper-21.pdf

My current code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import re
import fitz

def box_questions(pdf_path, canvas):
    pdf = PdfReader(pdf_path)
    num_pages = len(pdf.pages)

    for page_num in range(num_pages):
        page = pdf.pages[page_num]
        page_text = page.extract_text()
        page_width = page.mediabox.width
        page_height = page.mediabox.height

        top_margin = page_height * 0.05
        bottom_margin = page_height * 0.95

        doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
        page = doc[page_num]
        text_blocks = page.get_text("blocks")
        bold_numbers = []

        # Store the positions of bolded numbers
        bold_positions = []

        for block in text_blocks:
            for span in block[4]:
                if len(span) > 4 and span[1]:  # Check if the span is bold
                    bold_text = span[4]
                    matches = re.findall(r'\d+\.', bold_text)
                    for match in matches:
                        position = float(match) * page_height
                        if top_margin < position < bottom_margin:
                            bold_positions.append(position)

        # Sort the positions in ascending order
        bold_positions.sort()

        # Box the area between bolded numbers
        for i in range(0, len(bold_positions) - 1, 2):
            y1 = bold_positions[i]
            y2 = bold_positions[i + 1]
            x1 = 0
            x2 = page_width
            canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="red", width=2)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("PDF Questions Highlighter")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

pdf_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select PDF File")
if pdf_path:
    box_questions(pdf_path, canvas)
else:
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select a PDF file.")

root.mainloop()
```

I will combine this code with the following code after I figured out what is wrong with my bolded number recognition

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk, messagebox
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import re
import fitz
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

class PDFViewerApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("PDF Question Cropper")

        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.question_file = None
        self.answer_file = None

        self.question_label = ttk.Label(self.frame, text="No question file selected.")
        self.question_label.pack()

        self.select_question_button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Select Question PDF", command=self.select_question_pdf)
        self.select_question_button.pack()

        self.answer_label = ttk.Label(self.frame, text="No answer file selected.")
        self.answer_label.pack()

        self.select_answer_button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Select Answer PDF", command=self.select_answer_pdf)
        self.select_answer_button.pack()

        self.confirm_button = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Preview files", command=self.process_pdfs)
        self.confirm_button.pack()



        self.new_window = None
        self.pdf_canvas1 = None
        self.pdf_canvas2 = None
        self.scale_factor = 1.0  # Initialize the scale factor
        self.question_pages = None
        self.answer_pages = None
        self.current_canvas = None
        self.to_process_button = None

    def select_question_pdf(self):
        self.question_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Question PDF")
        if self.question_file:
            self.question_label.config(text=f"Question PDF: {os.path.basename(self.question_file)}")

    def select_answer_pdf(self):
        self.answer_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Answer PDF")
        if self.answer_file:
            self.answer_label.config(text=f"Answer PDF: {os.path.basename(self.answer_file)}")

    def process_pdfs(self):
        if self.question_file and not self.answer_file:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select an answer file.")
        elif self.answer_file and not self.question_file:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select a question file.")
        elif not self.question_file and not self.answer_file:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select both a question and an answer file.")
        else:
            self.open_new_window()

    def open_new_window(self):
        self.new_window = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.new_window.title("Question Cropper")

        self.pdf_viewer_frame = ttk.Frame(self.new_window)
        self.pdf_viewer_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        available_width = self.pdf_viewer_frame.winfo_width()
        canvas_width = available_width // 2

        canvas_height = self.pdf_viewer_frame.winfo_height() - 50

        self.pdf_canvas1 = tk.Canvas(self.pdf_viewer_frame, xscrollincrement=1)
        self.pdf_canvas2 = tk.Canvas(self.pdf_viewer_frame, xscrollincrement=1)

        self.scrollbar1 = ttk.Scrollbar(self.pdf_viewer_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.pdf_canvas1.yview)
        self.scrollbar2 = ttk.Scrollbar(self.pdf_viewer_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.pdf_canvas2.yview)

        self.pdf_canvas1.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar1.set, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
        self.pdf_canvas2.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar2.set, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)

        self.pdf_canvas1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.scrollbar1.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.pdf_canvas2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.scrollbar2.pack(side="left", fill="y")

        self.file_label = ttk.Label(self.new_window, text="Processing...")
        self.file_label.pack()

        self.display_pdfs()

    def display_pdfs(self):
        if self.question_file and self.answer_file:
            self.question_pages = convert_from_path(self.question_file)
            self.answer_pages = convert_from_path(self.answer_file)

            canvas_height = self.pdf_viewer_frame.winfo_height() - 50

            if self.question_pages and self.answer_pages:
                max_width = max(page.width for page in self.question_pages + self.answer_pages)
                max_height = max(page.height for page in self.question_pages + self.answer_pages)

                dy = max_height - 10
                canvas_width = max_width // 2
                self.scale_factor = canvas_width / max_width

                self.pdf_canvas1.config(width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height - 20)
                self.pdf_canvas2.config(width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height - 20)

                self.pdf_canvas1.imagelist = []
                self.pdf_canvas2.imagelist = []

                max_pages = max(len(self.question_pages), len(self.answer_pages))
                for page in range(max_pages):
                    if page < len(self.question_pages):
                        img1 = self.question_pages[page]
                        img1_resized = img1.resize(
                            (int(img1.width * self.scale_factor), int(img1.height * self.scale_factor))
                        )
                        photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img1_resized)
                        self.pdf_canvas1.create_image(0, page * dy, image=photo1, anchor=tk.NW)
                        self.pdf_canvas1.imagelist.append(photo1)

                    if page < len(self.answer_pages):
                        img2 = self.answer_pages[page]
                        img2_resized = img2.resize(
                            (int(img2.width * self.scale_factor), int(img2.height * self.scale_factor))
                        )
                        photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img2_resized)
                        self.pdf_canvas2.create_image(0, page * dy, image=photo2, anchor=tk.NW)
                        self.pdf_canvas2.imagelist.append(photo2)

                self.file_label.config(
                    text=f"Question File: {os.path.basename(self.question_file)} - Page {max_pages}\nAnswer File: {os.path.basename(self.answer_file)} - Page {max_pages}"
                )

                # Add mousewheel bindings to scroll canvas
                self.pdf_canvas1.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: self.on_canvas_scroll(event, self.pdf_canvas1))
                self.pdf_canvas2.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: self.on_canvas_scroll(event, self.pdf_canvas2))

        # Create the "Confirm and Process" button here
        self.to_process_button = ttk.Button(self.pdf_viewer_frame, heigth = max_height, text="Confirm and Process", command=self.process_select_box)
        self.to_process_button.pack()

    def on_canvas_scroll(self, event, canvas):
        if event.delta > 0:
            canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")
        elif event.delta < 0:
            canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units")

    def process_select_box(self):
        self.root.destroy
        self.open_thrid_window

    def open_thrid_window(self):
        self.new_window = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.new_window.title("Question selector")

        self.select_box_frame = ttk.Frame(self.new_window)
        self.select_box_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        available_width = self.pdf_viewer_frame.winfo_width()
        canvas_width = available_width // 2
        canvas_height = self.pdf_viewer_frame.winfo_height() - 50

        self.pdf_canvas1 = tk.Canvas(self.select_box_frame, xscrollincrement=1)
        self.scrollbar1 = ttk.Scrollbar(self.select_box_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.pdf_canvas1.yview)
        self.pdf_canvas1.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar1.set, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
        self.pdf_canvas1.pack(expand=True)

        self.file_label = ttk.Label(self.new_window, text="Processing...")
        self.file_label.pack()

        self.display_box_window()

    def display_box_window(self):
        if self.question_file:
            self.question_pages = convert_from_path(self.question_file)
            canvas_height = self.pdf_viewer_frame.winfo_height()-50

            if self.question_pages:
                max_width = max(page.width for page in self.question_pages)
                max_height = max(page.height for page in self.question_pages)

                dy = max_height - 10
                canvas_width = max_width
                self.scale_factor = canvas_width / max_width

                self.pdf_canvas1.config(width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height - 20)
                self.pdf_canvas1.imagelist = []

                max_pages = len(self.question_pages)
                for page in range(max_pages):
                    img1 = self.question_pages[page]
                    img1_resized = img1.resize(
                        (int(img1.width * self.scale_factor), int(img1.height * self.scale_factor))
                    )
                    photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img1_resized)
                    self.pdf_canvas1.create_image(0, page * dy, image=photo1, anchor=tk.NW)
                    self.pdf_canvas1.imagelist.append(photo1)

                self.file_label.config(
                    text=f"Question File: {os.path.basename(self.question_file)} - Page {max_pages}"
                )
                self.pdf_canvas1.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: self.on_canvas_scroll(event, self.pdf_canvas1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = PDFViewerApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Currently, after I select the PDF file and proceed to process it, the window does not display anything but a blank white screen. Additionally, there are no error messages, which leaves me confused about what might be wrong.

I'll appreciate any help provided to me.

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)